# Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'. , Cause: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 49:

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, gradle

I have been looking for a long time to find out how to solve this problem from my Android project, in fact I have a problem like ...., I have looked at all the possible tutorials and articles but nothing helps, I wonder if you can help me thank you

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable
> Resource compilation failed (Failed to compile values resource file C:\Driverapp\build\app\intermediates\incremental\release\mergeReleaseResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml. Cause: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 49: com.mighty.taxidriver.app-mergeReleaseResources-5:/values/values.xml). Check logs for more details.

Comment: Can you provide the code inside `android -> app ->  src -> main -> res -> values -> values.xml` ?

Comment: have you tried running `flutter clean` then `flutter pub get` at the root folder of your project ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.